# Getting hash tagged words from a string with PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to create an array of all of the hash tags in a given string and then loop through them and echo each one to show that they have been stored. What could I be doing wrong?

```
<?php

    $string= "Went for an awesome bike ride today! #biking";

    preg_match_all('/#(\w+)/',$string, $matches);

        foreach ($matches as $tag) {

            echo $tag;

        }

?>
```

Comment: If you don't know, use `var_dump()` on your variable first to find out its internal structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    foreach ($matches[1] as $tag) {
        echo $tag;
    }
```

is only outputting your matches.

`$matches` is a array with as many entries as you have parenthesis in your regex plus one.

See also: http://3v4l.org/MJCWE

Comment: @user2320500 As I said: see http://3v4l.org/MJCWE. There you'll notice what's going on... perhaps...

Comment: What is my regex and why plus one?

Comment: @user2320500 `/#(\w+)/` This is your regex. In the `$matches` array are two entries as you have one parenthesis part (`(\w+)`). (plus one, the total match)